# How to pinpoint the cause of freezes shortly after power-on?

Tags: freeze

My Win10 PC (E3 1230 v3, equivalent to i7 4770, 4x 8GB DDR3, GTX 1060) dated 2014 started freezing 1-5 minutes after power on. It happens even if I'm still in the BIOS.

The BIOS gives some readings for the PSU voltages which are all fine. I cannot check the Vcore but the other ones provided match my measurements and I also checked the 5 V and 3.3 V for ripple and it gives almost zero, so they should be fine.

Resetting CMOS didn't really help much. After reset it seemed to hold longer, but not on the next reboot.

I tested the memory with memtest86 and it was working fine, at least for few minutes until it froze as usual.

I tried disconnecting either half of the memory sticks, in cause it was memory related, but no change.

Nowadays it's not easy to find someone with desktop computers so asking someone to lend me an ATX PSU is not that easy.

How can I better isolate the issue to define whether I should replace the computing components or the power supply?

**Update**

As suggested in the comments, it was the motherboard.

Comment: It could be a hardware failure . The manufacturers should have Hardware Diagnostic Apps. Bad memory can cause what you are having.  It could be a Driver. Update all drivers (including BIOS). It could be root kit virus.  Kaspersky TDSS Killer finds these.

Comment: “ATC PSU”? Do you mean **ATX PSU**? If this is happening outside of an operating system it’s unlikely a root kit.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a computer and it was a capacitor in the motherboard had failed. I agree with previous commenters that it's probably hardware based.

Comment: @YourCodeMadeMeSuicidal thanks. It's surely hardware, but it's good to know that a mobo issue can cause it. Often instability is caused by the PSU, but in this case I was not so sure

Comment: To anyone voting for closure: I was clearly asking about how to pinpoint the cause between the two I was listing (motherboard/cpu, PSU. I don't think this is opinion based, the question is about the procedure for troubleshooting the issue.